# File permissions, sessions which are stored on database

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, permissions

Imagine that you have a site with many users and every user have their photos on their profiles. The photos are only visible to the owner of the photo. Actually I did all of these but my question is about permissions. When someone enters the  URL of the image which is stored in the database, he can easily see the picture full size. I want to avoid this.

- I want to make sure that the files should be only visible to those who have
  permissions.
- I want to know how to store files in the database with the permissions. Not just IMG but the others also.

I am using session inn PHP for managing the permissions.

Comment: [**No need to shout**](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25430223/1), the world can see you. Now, where'd I put my safety gogglers? Get that cat of yours off the keyboard; bad bad kitty cat.

Comment: Please don't post any code, I want to practice my telepathy. Haven't done so in a while, it must have been 2-3 questions ago.

Comment: *"I want to make sure that the files should be only visible to who have permissions."* - Define "permissions". Yet, if I understand this correctly, use a `WHERE` clause, if you're not already using one.